# How to render a pdf file using pdf.js?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf.js

I created an html file with content as below
**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./pdf.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./hello.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="the-canvas" style="border:1px solid black;"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

**hello.js** with content

```
PDFJS.disableWorker = true;
var pf = PDFJS.getDocument('./helloworld.pdf')
pf.then(function(pdf) {
  pdf.getPage(1).then(function(page) {
    var scale = 1.5;
    var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);

    //
    // Prepare canvas using PDF page dimensions
    //
    var canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.height = viewport.height;
    canvas.width = viewport.width;

    //
    // Render PDF page into canvas context
    //
    var renderContext = {
      canvasContext: context,
      viewport: viewport
    };
    page.render(renderContext);
  });
});
```

But the pdf is not shown correctly when I point the browser to index.html.
I want the user to be able to select a pdf file on his computer and show that pdf in browser window.

Comment: You may have a problem accessing the local file system. How are you serving/accessing this? `http:`? `file:`?

Comment: Also I assume that extra backtick on line 3 is a typo.

Comment: @Joe I am accessing it via file: I don't know why it would matter whether I am accessing it via http: or file: after all it's JavaScript and should work either way.

Comment: Don't assume it. In some situations (maybe or maybe not this situation) it does matter. See this: http://ejohn.org/blog/tightened-local-file-security/

Comment: Hi, I had the same problem trying to paint a image on canvas last year: when I loaded the page (and the image) from ´file:\\´ in Google chrome the canvas accepted it but didn't allowed me to get the image from canvas (with toDataURL). I installed Apache locally and tested again from it and it was working OK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are hitting this problem when using the `file:` protocol rather than `http:` or `https:`. There are different security considerations in play between the different protocols.

Here's [a blog post about using `XMLHttpRequest` with local files](http://ejohn.org/blog/tightened-local-file-security/), and a [discussion on a Mozilla Firefox ticket](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=230606).

There are a few tickets (including [this one](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/2354) and [this one](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/3134)) on the project that may provide pointers. A comment from [this ticket](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/1913) says:

> Typical pdf.js use cases requires to use a web server and modern HTML5 browser.

I suggest **to fix your problem** you just run this through a web server to use the `http` protocol. Nginx and Apache are easy to install and set up.

If that doesn't work generate pdf.js and pdf.worker.js for your system using [this](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js#building-pdfjs) if the above step doesn't work.

Comment: created a node server, put the helloworld.pdf and pdf.js in static files and served index.html(http://paste.ubuntu.com/7157553/), still no pdf in the served file.
http://localhost:3000/javascripts/helloworld.pdf however shows the pdf meaning that it is available.Maybe i am doing something wrong here.

Comment: other than 404 for /javascripts/pdf.worker.js (http://paste.ubuntu.com/7157625/)no other error in the console. Also the script tag 
<script src="http://localhost:3000/javascripts/pdf.worker.js"></script> is added to index.html I don't know how.
I don't think running a server is the solution because when i clone the pdf.js repo from github and open the helloworld example in browser(https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/tree/master/examples/helloworld) it works fine.

Comment: That script tag is not present in index.html, so I don't know how I would go about fixing it. Still I created a blank pdf.worker.js.
Now 404 error is not on console. Now there is a warning "Warning: Setting up fake worker." from pdf.js.

Comment: Why do you expect this to work if you've not put in all the source files? Is the extra script tag in the DOM or in the source of the HTML page? If it's the latter then you're not serving the file you think you're serving.

Comment: The extra script tag is present when I open the console and use the inspector. It is not in the index.html that I wrote. When I comment out `var pf = PDFJS.getDocument('./helloworld.pdf');` then the extra script tag doesn't show up in the inspector.

Comment: Well the PDFJs code is adding the relevant DOM element. That's no great surprise. Did you follow the instructions at https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js#getting-the-code ? I can't really help you further. Good luck.

Comment: Got it to work, even without the server. Used the files generated after running `node make` on pdf.js repo. I guess you have to build for your system and can't use pdf.js and pdf.worker.js generated by someone else. Thanks for all the help.