# Trouble using pdf.js to read local file

Tags: javascript, pdf.js

I downloaded PDF.js from http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/ and modified the file to set:

```
DEFAULT_URL='G:/10.pdf'
```

However, when opening the file locally (without publishing to a web server) I receive the following error:

> PDF.js v1.0.712 (build: 6969ed4) Message: Unexpected server response
>   (0) while retrieving PDF "G:/10.pdf"

I'm trying to load the pdf file into a `Uin8Array`. Can someone help me?

Comment: does changing it to `'file:///G:/10.pdf'` make any difference?

Comment: are you getting this error in all the browsers? and when you try with publishing to a server what is happening?

Comment: when I changen it to 'file:///G:/10.pdf',there are something wrong in " xhr.open('GET', file);
      xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
      xhr.send();"    send failed,cross-domain access happened.

Comment: yes,all the browser,when I try with publishing to a server,everything will be ok.because xhr.send();can be ok.

Comment: yes,all the browser,when I try with publishing to a server,everything will be ok.because xhr.send();can be ok.But what I  need is the first way

Comment: based on very limited amount of information provided here: some of web browsers cannot access file system via XHR (e.g. Chrome or IE). if you are writing custom application, you can use web browser control to fetch local data that can be passed as array to PDF.js

Comment: Have you seen: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22663700/19308 dealing with the issue of loading local files?